# How do I add static url inside CSS file?

Tags: django

I have a CSS class that I need to add a background to it. How do I point my background to the static folder in Django?

E.g:

```html
.background {
 background: url(img/my-background.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Do I have to add this with a template tag in my base.html instead? Like this:

```
<style>.background { background: url({% static "img/my-background.png" %}) no-repeat; } </style>
```

Comment: I think you just have to specify your static directory(with your image) and then you can access your image with a CSS rule, whether it's inline CSS or external.

Comment: also, is your app named img? Probably not, so your path should most likely be either /static/your_app/my-background.png  or in case you opt to use {%load staticfiles%} then it's probably /your_app/my-background.png. Provided that the full path is /your_app/static/your_app/my-background.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use **Relative Path** instead ?

**1) settings.py**

```
import os
from path import path

SETTINGS_FILE_FOLDER = path(__file__).parent.abspath()

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_FILE_FOLDER, '../static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   STATIC_PATH,
)
```

**2) app_name/templates/xyz.html**

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}app_name/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

**3) static/app_name/css/style.css**

```
.class-name {
  background-image: url('../img/logo.png');
}
```

**4) and this should be the folder structure:**

```
project_folder
│   settings.py
│   manage.py    
│
└───app_name
│    │   views.py
│    │   urls.py
│    │   ...
│    │
│    ├───templates
│    │   │   xyz.html
│    │   │   abc.html
│    │   │   ...
│
│
static
│
└───app_name
│    │
│    ├───css
│    │   │   style.css
│    │   │   ...
│    │
│    └───img
│    │   │   logo.png
│    │   │   ...
```